# Insert duplicate records in a weak entity Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

So I'm doing some entity framework practices and as a project I wanted to create a database that stores a list of clients, some products and when and how many of a product where bought.

I created an entity "Receipt".

```
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }

[Required]
public DateTime RecieptDate { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("FKClient")]
public Client Client { get; set; }

public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

And EF creates an implicit table in the Database to store the relationship between `Receipt` and `Products`, but the thing is that I want to store multiple records of the same product in the same receipt. I wonder is there a way to store duplicate records on the implicit `ReceiptProducts` table?

If not, is there a better way to approach this problem?
(Edit) -Added the product entity

```
class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1,double.MaxValue)]
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public List<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the `Product` entity code. If you added the `Receipt` list to the product entity, the relation between two entities is `many-to-many`.

Comment: So you just want a `List<ReceiptProduct> ReceiptProducts` property?

Comment: DavidG the problem is that EF auto generates such table, and I can't instantiate the class to create such list